# Randomized Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, random, quicksort

Two ways to implement randomized Quicksort,

Method1: Choosing a random pivot

Method2: Generating a random permutation of the input and feeding it to a quicksort that chooses the first element as pivot

Is method1 same as method2 in terms of randomization?

Note: Looks like Method2 produces all partitions equally likely but method1 does not. So if they are not the same, then I want to understand what the performance impact is.

Comment: I'd say yes. The binary partition at each step has follows the same law in both methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In either case, the probability of any particular element being selected as the pivot is 1/len(input). (However, the second method is almost certainly slower by a constant factor, since it will require an extra linear pass to generate the random permutation.)

Comment: But the for a particular input, the 2nd method has all the n! permutations equally likely, but the 1st method doesn't change the relative ordering of input, so it doesn't include all possible partitions for an input. So I feel there is a difference, but not sure what impact it would have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all possible partitions". The set of elements that are greater or less than the pivot element doesn't depend at all on their order.

Comment: I am sorry I got confused, I understand it now. Thanks